# Place Date in Description when moved to different OU

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am not sure if this is possible, but i am wondering if i could create a powershell script that would move any/all users listed in a CSV file to a different OU and add the date in the Desription field in AD? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  We are not going to write the script for you. You are going to need to spend some time doing putting the effort in yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are legitimately asking for help or asking for somebody to do your homework. I'll get you started by telling you the commands you need.

If your CSV file has a column labeled usernames...

```
[load the AD module here]
$userlist = Import-Csv [supply options here]
foreach ($user in $userlist.usernames)
    {
    $userObj = Get-ADUser $user -prop *
    Move-ADObject [supply options here]
    Set-ADUser [supply options here]
    }
```

That's the basic idea. Now you can Google the details.

Comment: thanks! not at all. i wanna do the script myself. i just couldn't figure out how I would get my script to put the date in the description when a user is moved.

Answer (score 0):

Zach's solution is good. You can use Get-Date to, well, get the date. For example:

```
[string]$date = Get-Date -Format g
```

Will result in "5/13/2015 10:42 AM" (depends on your locale)

Then write it to the user description with:

```
Set-ADUser $user -Description $date
```